# How to distribute the number of elements in a bucket so that it is Within a Range - Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, knapsack-problem, np

I have been solving a problem where in say I have 50 elements
`n1, n2, n3, ... , n50`.

Now I have a limited number of buckets, say 5 buckets and the bucket can hold a range from, say 100 to 150 only (which is nothing but the sum of elements in that bucket), but neither less than 100, nor more than 150.

Which algorithm is most suitable for solving this problem, such that all the 5 buckets are used and all the elements `(n1, n2, n3, ...)` are also used up.

If a bucket is not used or if any element is left out, then the algorithm just returns "InvalidConditionsFound".

I tried Knapsack which gives you a combination as close to a gived number, but how to get it within a range and also make sure that it chooses wisely such that all the buckets are getting filled, and not that two bucket gets 150 full  and the other bucket is only at, say 50

Comment: Does the bucket range refer to the sum which must be contained in it, or is it the range of the individual numbers in that bucket?

Comment: Did I get it right that only the constraints must be fulfilled (i.e. each bucket between 100 and 150; all elements used) but otherwise there is no requirement to find the "best" solution.

Comment: What have you tried?  What is its performance, or if it didn't work, in what conditions is it buggy? Do you have code?

Comment: Hey, can you tell what is the max number of elements and buckets in your problem?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen , it is the Sum of the numbers inside the bucket

Comment: have you tried modeling the problem as an integer program and then using some solver to see how it goes?

Comment: Hi @Henry , Yes you are Correct in understanding the constraints, and there is no requirement to find the best solution, but If that can be done too, then well and Good!!!!!

Comment: Hi @Lorehead , I donot have a code ready for this, my approach was to treat it as Knapsack problem with the maximum weight as 150(the upper limit of the range) and then distribute the extra elements(numbers) to those buckets which were LESS than 100 (say X) , from these buckets which were MORE than 100(say Y), in a manner that X does not fall below 100 and Y gets raised to 100 or above.! But this will not be a standard algorithm or some special case of any standared algorithm for solving a problem

Comment: hi @vish4071, Max Number of elements can be anything, say 50 elements (50 numbers) and buckets can be also anything, we 5 buckets, we are checking if a Solution exists for a given array of numbers and a fixed number of buckets , having all the constraints satisfied

Comment: @ArghoChatterjee, I was asking max number as it helps in thinking what paradigm can be used.

Comment: Hi @vish4071, my mistake in understanding your question , ok, so max number can be say , less than 150, which is nothing but my upper limit. Did I answer your question correctly.

Comment: Hi All, Can this Problem Be solved, I came to know from a few colleges of mine is that this is a NP-Complete problem and there isn't any efficient algorithm to solve this, yes it is a variation to Knapsack problem though. Hence was advised to use use simple heuristics instead. Can anybody comment as to if this is true , with your experience and understanding of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to model this as an integer program. Let's assume there are "m" numbers y_1, y_2, ..., y_m and "n" buckets. Define variables x_ij, with an index "i" for each of the numbers you are trying to assign and an index "j" for each bucket. These are binary variables indicating if each number is assigned to each bucket.

Now you have two sets of logical constraints. First, you need to assign each number to exactly one bucket. You can do this by adding the following constraint for each number "i":

```
x_i1 + x_i2 + ... + x_in = 1
```

You also have the range constraints on each bucket "j":

```
100 <= y_1 x_1j + y_2 x_2j + ... + y_m x_mj <= 150
```

Really you are just looking for any feasible solutions, so you can just set the objective to 0 and treat this as a feasibility problem.

While you are solving an NP-complete problem so this is a theoretically challenging exercise, you may find that modern optimization software can solve the problem for problem sizes of interest to you.

To give a sense of the scalability, consider the following implementation using the `lpSolve` package in R; it returns the assignments from numbers to buckets when a valid assignment exists and otherwise returns a vector of NA values:

```
library(lpSolve)
range.assign <- function(weights, n, min.sum, max.sum) {
  m <- length(weights)
  one.mat <- t(sapply(1:m, function(i) c(replicate(n, 1*((1:m) == i)))))
  w.mat <- t(sapply(1:n, function(j) c(rep(0, m*(j-1)), weights, rep(0, m*(n-j)))))
  mod <- lp(objective.in = rep(0, n*m),
            const.mat = rbind(one.mat, w.mat, w.mat),
            const.dir = rep(c("=", ">=", "<="), c(m, n, n)),
            const.rhs = rep(c(1, min.sum, max.sum), c(m, n, n)),
            all.bin=TRUE)
  if (mod$status == 0) {
    apply(matrix(mod$solution, nrow=m), 1, function(x) which(x >= 0.999))
  } else {
    rep(NA, m)
  }
}
range.assign(1:5, 2, 5, 10)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2
range.assign(1:5, 2, 5, 6)
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

I tested this with `m` weights randomly sampled from `[1, 2, ..., 10]`, acceptable range for a bucket `[100, 150]`, and total number of buckets `n = ceiling(5.5*m / 125)`. I saw the following runtime scaling:

- `m = 100, n = 5`: 0.1 seconds
- `m = 200, n = 9`: 0.6 seconds
- `m = 300, n = 14`: 2.2 seconds
- `m = 400, n = 18`: 16.9 seconds

It seems like the problem can be solved exactly using free solvers for problems with a dozen buckets and a few hundred weights (and this weight vector structure). Of course your complexity result suggests it won't be efficiently solvable for huge problems, but you may be able to solve instances with sizes that interest you. Further optimizations may be possible by:

1. Using commercial solvers such as Gurobi or cplex (both are non-free in general but free for academic use).
2. Inputting the constraint matrix in a sparse format.

Comment: hey @Josiber , I am trying to implement it in java, if you can provide any sudo code or video tutorial link of your implementation would really help full, again thanks for your efforts.!!!!

Comment: @ArghoChatterjee I would encourage you to try implementing it yourself and to post a new question is you run into any implementation issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a k-partitioning problem which is more commonly known as the [bin-packing problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) Since this problem is NP-Complete there will not be an 'efficient' solution. However if you'd look around on the internet I'm sure you can find tons of code examples so you and your (*cough*) "collegues" can solve this problem.

Comment: I don't believe the classical bin packing  supports non-zero lower bounds for the amount assigned to each bin, though perhaps one of the many variants allows these constraints.

Comment: hi @Glubus, I donot understand how it is a simple partition problem. Can you please explain more about it. Knapsap is a special case of Bin Packing Problem, if I am not wrong, so did you mean to suggest to use Knapsap ? I have already implemented it but it falls short of the scenario mentioned in the question

Comment: Hey Argho, admittedly I did not do enough research to give you a straight solution to your problem (I am currently at my job so I can't really get deep into it). However I feel like your problem looks like the bin-packing problem and I expect therefor that you can find or create your solution by manipulating some existing solution to a different problem. I recommend you reading into the problem / solutions to different problems and find out if you can derive a solution to your own problem. If I have time tonight I'll give it a go myself.

Comment: If you feel like you need a solution faster and you don't want to read papers and whatnot, take a look at @josilber 's answer, it's a different approach but modelling your problem as an integer problem might work!